# Laravel: Where can I write my beforeDetach

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to write my own validator before the detach function.

For example, I have users and groups, with a many-to-many relationship. It is not possible to remove the last admin from the group unless the user is the last member of the group. I wouldn't like to always write the same validation in the controllers.

It is pretty straightforward to write beforeSave and afterSave by writing

```
public function save()
{
   // Before save 
   parent::save();
   // After save
}
```

But currently I don't handle where I should write my beforeDetach.

I call the detach method like this

```
$group->users()->detach($user_id);
```

I want to in the background always passively check for some conditions to be met.

Currently I haven't found a solution. If it is not possible natively how should one go about implementing it?

**Edit**

Think it would be even cooler if I could have methods like these:

```
$group->users()->detach($user_id);
$group->users()->validateAndDetach($user_id)
```

Comment: Might have found the solution, I should extend BelongsToMany class. And when I set up the relationships I should use my new class. Gonna try this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution, although not the prettiest. Any pointers to improve this are welcome.

First of all I extended the BelongsToMany class:

```
class BelongsToManyGroupUser extends  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    public function detach($ids = array(), $touch = true)
    {
        // Before detach
        parent::detach();
        // After detach
    }
}
```

Then I created a new method in my Group model:

```
public function belongsToManyGroupUser($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null)
{
    $caller = $this->getBelongsToManyCaller();
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
    $instance = new $related;
    $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();
    if (is_null($table))
    {
        $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
    }
    $query = $instance->newQuery();
    return new BelongsToManyGroupUser($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey);
}
```

Where I pretty much copied the base of this function and just returned my new BelongsToManyGroupUser object.

And I set up the relationship like this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToManyGroupUser('User', 'group_user');
}
```

What I don't like about this solution yet is the fact that I copied 10 lines of code from the BelongsToMany class. If those were to change I have to manually make changes.
Also I made a change from:

```
return new BelongsToMany($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $caller['function']);`
```

To:

```
return new BelongsToManyGroupUser($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $caller);
```

notice the last parameter. Former gave me errors and since the $caller is already a String which the constructor expects, I just passed $caller as the last parameter. I'm not sure of the effects yet.

**edit:**

And now I can write my own validateAndDetach function in the BelongsToManyGroupUser class.